# How to configure async timeout in embedded jetty using spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am using an embedded jetty container using spring boot. If my request take too long, Jetty fails on 503. In jetty logs I see this:

Dispatch after async timeout

So, I assume the async timed out. However, I couldn't find where to update this timeout to a higher value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Async Timeout can refer to Async Processing (aka AsyncContext from Servlet 3.0) or Async I/O (from Servlet 3.1).  Which one are you concerned about?

Comment: Judging from the debugging I did it refers to the AsyncContext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring mvc supports an application property, spring.mvc.async.request-timeout, which is the timeout in milliseconds for asynchronous request handling. 
Verified with spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `JettyServerCustomizer` to your application context to customize Jetty:

```
@Bean
JettyServerCustomizer jettyCustomizer() {
    return new JettyServerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Server server) {
            //do something
        }
    };
}
```

But the configuration you're looking for I think is at the `AsyncContext` level, and that's handled by Spring MVC. Try this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public static class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
    }
 }
```